# Actual Development process in Yii framework

Tags: process, yii

I am doing an application in Yii Framework.I have progressed to some way like `setup the application,data modelling,CRUD for models,migrations`.I think all these should be done in a planned process.Can some one tell me what is the actual development process for doing an application?All of your suggestions and advice will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can follow the steps mentioned in these links:
 1. http://tommasodargenio.com/tutorial-8-easy-steps-to-create-a-web-application-with-yii-part-4-and-last-201.htm
 2. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.convention

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following resources:

- Development workflow:
  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.workflow
- MVC best practices:
  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.best-practices
- The "Yii Cookbook" has a closing chapter on deployment but that's a little ahead of its just - just FYI...